# Duplicated password validation messages ONLY IF new password is 1 char long

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My problem is password validation message appears twice in Registration and Change Password forms. As most posts/solutions points out "groups", how do I implement it into my code below? I tried to implement other solved examples as shown below but I cannot get it working. Maybe because I never worked FOSUserBundle before.

- [FOSUserBundle - Validation for username, password or email
  fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702353/fosuserbundle-validation-for-username-password-or-email-fields)
- [Duplicated errors for constraints when using several validation
  groups](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4427)
- [Symfony2 FOSUserBundle extending registration form causes duplicate
  email to validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230053/symfony2-fosuserbundle-extending-registration-form-causes-duplicate-email-to-val)
- [validating fosuserbundle registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276327/validating-fosuserbundle-registration-form)
- [Validation of a form - I'm getting the labels two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501569/validation-of-a-form-im-getting-the-labels-two-times)

**myapp/app/config/config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: WebsiteBundle\Entity\User
    model_manager_name: websitemanager
    registration:
        form:
            type: website_user_registration
    change_password:
        form:
            type: fos_user_change_password
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
```

**WebsiteBundle/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml**

```
fos_user:
    password:
        short: "[-Inf,Inf]The password must contain at least 8 characters"
```

**services.xml**

```
<service id="myapp_website.registration.form.type"
              class="myapp\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType">
      <tag name="form.type" alias="website_user_registration" />
      <argument>myapp\WebsiteBundle\Entity\User</argument>
</service>
```

**WebsiteBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php**

```
namespace myapp\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add(
            'terms',
            'checkbox',
            [
                'label' => 'Older than 18',
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'Are you older than 18?',
                    ]),
                ],
                'required' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'website_user_registration';
    }
}
```

**validation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">

        <property name="plainPassword">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>ResetPassword</value>
                    <value>ChangePassword</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
            <constraint name="Length">
                <option name="min">8</option>
                <option name="minMessage">fos_user.password.short</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                    <value>ResetPassword</value>
                    <value>ChangePassword</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
        <property name="email">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">Please enter your email address</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">Please enter your name</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
        </property>

    </class>

</constraint-mapping>
```

**Twig**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<form action="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
    {{ form_row(form.current_password, {'label': 'Current Password'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, {'label': 'New Password'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, {'label': 'Confirm Password'}) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <br /><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Change password" />
</form>
```

**HTML result**

```
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" />

<label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second">Confirm password</label>
<input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" />
```

**Errors**
When I have `validators.en.yml` in code-base.

[image: 8-char]

When I remove `validators.en.yml` from code-base.

[image: screenshot from 2016-01-05 14 28 29]

Comment: could it be that the confirm password's validation message is appearing next to the password field? in that case its a styling issue?

Comment: If I delete `<value>ChangePassword</value>` from `<property name="plainPassword"><constraint name="Length">....` error gets reduced to one but this time obviously I can set password in any length.

Comment: Previous comment tells that extra validation is done from Default group. Are you sure that there is no constraint on User __entity__ (not model) itself ?

Comment: No there is nothing on entitiy. All I have is above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the group_sequence feature for validations.

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    group_sequence:
        - User
        - Strict
    getters:
        passwordLegal:
            - 'IsTrue':
                message: 'The password cannot match your username'
                groups: [Strict]
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

> In this example, it will first validate all constraints in the group
>   User (which is the same as the Default group). Only if all constraints
>   in that group are valid, the second group, Strict, will be validated.

This is taken straight of the Symfony documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence

However personally I could never get this feature to work.