# FOSUserBundle doesn't detect duplicated username

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, registration

If I override `register.html.twig` from FOSUserBundle, registration does work properly but when a duplicated username or email is entered, instead of showing an error message I get a `UniqueConstraintViolationException`.

I saw this solution but it doesn't actually work for me, maybe to old?

[Symfony2 FOSUserBundle extending registration form causes duplicate email to validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230053/symfony2-fosuserbundle-extending-registration-form-causes-duplicate-email-to-val)

I'm not overriding RegistrationController so far as registration process doen't require any extra functionality.

This is my `register.html.twig` template:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block fos_user_content %}
    {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.username, {'label': 'Username:', 'attr': {'placeholder': 'mail@example.com'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(form.plainPassword) }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

**My versions**:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.1.*",
```

Comment: Please add symfony version and fosuser version being used, possibly from your composer.lock

Comment: Why did the linked solution not work for you? Did you still get the exception? Did you clear caches in between tries?

Comment: The solution I linked has no effect at all, I still get the same exception (as I remark I try to avoid to overrwrite controller so my use case is not exactly as that solution, but the validator should work anyway). And yes, cache was cleared.